# Can two foreach loop be used simultaneously in one rule in a makeppfile?

Tags: perl, foreach, makepp

I have two variables which are basically List of Clients and other variable is the clock domains of those clients.
The first variable is the list of clients

```
$CLIENTS
```

and the second variable are the clock domains of the corresponding clients

```
$CLIENTS_CLOCK_DOMAIN
```

I want to write a rule like this where $(SOME_PATH) is just a path where the .o files are there

```
MV_$(foreach)_ACI_$(foreach).c:$(SOME_PATH)/$(foreach)_X_$(foreach).o:foreach $CLIENTS foreach $CLIENTS_CLOCK_DOMAIN
    $(CC) $(foreach)_X_$(foreach).o $<  > $@
```

here the first foreach loop should start for $CLIENTS and the second one for $CLIENTS_CLOCK_DOMAIN

Is it possible by any means or if any one can tell an alternate method?